# How to resume downloads of large files in ios

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using downloadTask of URLSession to download a large file. The problem i am facing is how to provide pause and resume functionality. I have read that cancelling the downloadTask with resumeData gives back resumeData which can be used next time to resume the download. But for a really large file, this resumeData can be very large (i think. depending on file size and at what stage download is paused it can be very large). How do i persist this large resumeData so that i can use it next time to resume download.
Also there can be multiple downloads at the same time, which increases the same problem more.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resume data blob does **not** contain the actual received data.  If it did, you wouldn't be able to resume downloading a multi-gigabyte file on a 32-bit architecture.

What it contains is a bunch of metadata for the transfer:

- A URL on disk where the temporary file is stored.
- A time stamp indicating when the fetch began so it can ask the server if the file has changed since then.
- The request URL.
- The set of request headers.
- Probably some UUIDs.

And it might just be the URL of a metadata file on disk that contains the things listed above.  I'm not sure which.

Either way, you will not get a multi-gigabyte `resumeData` blob.  That would be devastating.  The whole point of a download task is that it downloads to disk, not to memory.